# NSStatusItem with Popover

Tags: macos, view, statusbar, popover, nsstatusitem

I'm trying to make a status bar app, but i'm having some problems.
How can i show a popover with a custom view after the status item is clicked?
Example code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Popup](https://github.com/shpakovski/Popup). It is an open source project where you can learn all about how to do this by running it and dissecting it.